# php artisan migrate error

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I have a problem to execute this command:

```
$ php artisan migrate:install
```

And I get this error:

> {"error":{"type":"Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException","message":"Class 'PDO' not found","file":"/home/site/public_html/laravel/app/config/database.php","line":16}}

Comment: Sounds like you may not have PDO enabled in your php configuration.

Comment: You may want to take a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19909574/php-fatal-error-class-pdo-not-found-using-laravel4