# Laravel 5 : Call to undefined function Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\mb_internal_encoding()

Tags: php, laravel

I am using https://github.com/bestmomo/laravel5-example and just cloned it. But i got this message. Googled everywhere but no results. Perhaps someone experiencing this? I am newbie to L5

[image: Error displayed]

Comment: try to read on this,
https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/6891

Comment: I commented out the code : mb_internal_encoding('UTF-8'); in BootStrap\LoadConfiguration.php and the site worked normally. But still not a good solution i think

Comment: For Laravel 5 on CentOS 7, see my answer to another [post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33711345/3718465).

Answer (score 11):

had the same problem, solution is to enable the mbstring php extension:
https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/call-to-undefined-function

In my case (AMPPS), I had to disable and reenable it + apache restart.

Comment: +1 for mentioning disabling and re-enabling it in AMPPS... had same problem and did that—now works fine.